# Custom Keyboard: Switch keyboard button

Tags: android

I want to add a button to my custom keyboard for changing back to google keyboard from my custom keyboard.

I reffered: https://github.com/tutsplus/Android-CustomKeyboard
this tutorial. 
So if possible help me step by step way to add that button. 
That will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imported: `import android.provider.Settings;`
then added a intent, `private Intent gk = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS);`

and, in Onkey: `InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);`

then a switch case: `case 333:
                gk.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                im.showInputMethodPicker();
                break;`

thanks to samrik.